# jquery sum column if row checked

Tags: php, jquery, loops, checkbox, sum

I have this table into a modal form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <!-- Record list -->
    <table id="tabscarichi" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style='border-collapse: collapse;' >
        <tr style='background: whitesmoke;'>
            
            <th>Check</th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Formulario</th>
            <th>EER</th>
            <th>Data FR</th>
            <th>Q.tà</th>
        </tr>

            <?php 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM registro_c_s where stato_carico='1'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $fr = $row['formulario'];
                $data = $row['data_fr'];
                $eer = $row['codice_eer'];
                $qta = $row['quantità'];
                $stato = $row['stato_carico'];
            ?>
        <tr>

            <!-- Checkbox -->
            <td><input type='checkbox' class="box" name='update[]' value='<?= $id ?>' ></td>
            
            <td><?= $id ?></td>
            <td><?= $fr ?></td>
            <td><?= $eer ?></td>
            <td><?= $data ?></td>
            <td class="qta_scarichi"><?= $qta ?></td>

        </tr>
            <?php

            }
            
            ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm trying to write a script to sum values of class .qta_scarichi and reporting it in another input number with .qtas class.

I tried this:

```
$('.box').change(function(){
   var total = 0;
   $('.box:checked').each(function(){
        total+=parseFloat($(this).parent().next('td').find('.qta_scarichi').text());
   });
   $('#qtà').val(total); 
});
```

But when i check some rows..nothing happen.. #qtà is the id of the input number that i want to fill..

Comment: _"and reporting it in another input number with .qtas class"_ - and you did attempt to select _that_ with `$('#qtà')` ...? Well that would obviously be wrong, you are selecting an element with the ID `qtà` there.

Comment: i don't understand.. i want to bind the value of var total to the input #qtà.. the input has class .qtas and id #qtà ..

Comment: where is input or td with this id `#qta`?

Comment: in another div with class form-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).parent().next('td')` just selects `<td><?= $id ?></td>`, which doesn't contain `.qta_scarichi`.

Use `$(this).closest('tr').find('.qta_scarichi')`.

I suspect you may have intended ".siblings('td')`.` .next()` only selects the immediately following element.

Comment: thank you for your answer but when i click on the checkbox, nothings happens..

Comment: Try adding `console.log()` statements so you can see where it's failing.

Comment: with the help of console i understood that if i refer to one checkbox created out of the form.. it's ok.. 
if i call the event change on the checkbox in the form.. i havent log on the console.. i must add that the checkbox in the form.. is in a table created by a loop with php ...i extract some data from sql

Comment: Problem found! in table with id="tabscarichi" i have the following script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#tabscarichi').hide(); 
    $('#tipo').change(function(){
        if($('#tipo').val() == 'scarico') {
            $('#tabscarichi').show(); 
             console.log('0');
        } else {
            $('#tabscarichi').hide(); 
        } 
    });
});
</script>

```

i choose to show the table with a select... if i disable the script.. the css selector works! But i don't understand why..

Comment: You can post your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem found! in table with id="tabscarichi" i have the following script:

````
$(function() { 
$('#tabscarichi').hide(); 
$('#tipo').change(function(){ 
if($('#tipo').val() == 'scarico') { 
$('#tabscarichi').show(); 
console.log('0'); } 
else { $('#tabscarichi').hide(); 
} }); }); </script> ``` 

i choose to show the table with a select... if i disable the script.. the css selector works! But i don't understand why..
````